# Getting a routing error for form_tag in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

An custom action `mass_onboard_result` was declared in routes.rb for `engine_config`:

```
collection do
  put :mass_onboard_result
end
```

In controller for engine configs, there is definition for `mass_onboard_result`:

```
def mass_onboard_result
   code here
end
```

Here is the view which starts with `form_tag`:

```
<%= form_tag mass_onboard_result_engine_configs_path do %>
  .......
  <%=submit_tag 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

When clicking `Save` on the form, there is an routing error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/onboard_data_upload/engine_configs/mass_onboard_result"

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

In output of `rake routes`, there is:

```
mass_onboard_result_engine_configs PUT    /engine_configs/mass_onboard_result(.:format)
```

What could cause the error. Is it the declaration in routes.rb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined your route as a `put` route, but your form is creating a `post` request.

If you add `method: :put` into the form_tag options, is the problem resolved?

Comment: We tried again with :method => :put and the error is the same: Template is missing. Missing template onboard_data_uploadx/engine_configs/mass_onboard_result. The mass_onboard_result is an action (like create/update) and it is supposed to process the data input from another form.

Comment: Is it something related to form_tag? We used the :mathod => :put with form_for before and it worked fine.

Comment: that's not the same error, it's a completely different error. Now your request is getting past the routing error, to the action you're submitting it to, and the problem is with that `mass_onboard_result` action - it doesn't have a template to render. If that action should be processing data and then redirecting to another page, now you need to add that functionality into that controller action.

Comment: sevenseacat, you are right. Template missing is a very different error. The error disappears after adding code the the def of mass_onboard_result.

Answer (score 1):

The error is written here:

```
No route matches [POST]...
```

A typical problem for Rails devs (especially ones starting out), is to overlook the importance of the [`HTTP verb`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#http-verb-constraints) in the routes structure.

--

**Fix**

When you use a `form`, it will default to sending the data via the `POST` verb. However, your routes have clearly defined your route as using the `PUT` verb:

```
collection do
  put :mass_onboard_result
end
```

To fix this, you either need to change the route to accept `POST` responses, or your `form` to send a `PUT` request:

```
#config/routes.rb
collection do
   match :mass_onboard_result, via [:post, :put]
end
```

-or-

```
#view
<%= form_tag your_path, method: :put %>
```

Comment: mass_onboard_result is an action like create/update. With :method => :put added in form_tag, there is an error saying Missing template onboard_data_updatex/engine_configs/mass_onboard_result.

Comment: Is it something related to form_tag? We used the :mathod => :put with form_for before and it worked fine.

Comment: This is the code with :method added:<%= form_tag mass_onboard_result_engine_configs_path, :method => :put do %>

Comment: Also tried: form_tag :url => {action: 'mass_onboard_result'}, method: :put do and the error is the same routing error.